# NSPipe and System() - iPhone SDK Cocoa

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, terminal

I need to add this section into my application where the user would enter in a terminal command for example "killall SpringBoard" and when the user presses the button  it would run the command. I know that if you use the System("") function you can run the terminal command. But how about from a textbox?

My next question is if it is possible to retrieve the result of the terminal command using NSPipe? If so how? *Note I am using the phrase 'terminal command' since i'm not really sure what its called (If someone knows please tell me...). Basically the same thing as the commands in MobileTerminal...*

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on submitting your app to the AppStore, it will never get approved with a feature set like that.

Answer (score 0):

> … how about from a textbox?

Rhetorical question: What do your views have to do with the `system` function?

> My next question is if it is possible to retrieve the result of the terminal command using NSPipe?

Yes.

> If so how?

Abandon the `system` function, and use `fork` and one of [the `exec` functions](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/execl.3.html) directly. (There's no NSTask on the iPhone—not in the iPhone API documentation, anyway.)

Considering your plan is to kill the SpringBoard, I hope that you're targeting the jailbreak platform, not the App Store. Like greg, I would expect Apple to reject your app if you try any such thing. I can't even imagine why you want to do that.